# How to post stream on Azure Media service INGEST URL?

Tags: azure, video-streaming, azure-media-services

How can I post stream on Azure Media service INGEST URL?

if INGESTurl support RTMP.

Example

rtmp://channel001-XXXmediaservices.channel.mediaservices.windows.net:135/live/403d19563ed744e89da91748c6224789991

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) to ingest stream from video camera or desktop.

Example of bash script in raspberry pi :

```
#!/bin/bash
modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
INGESTURI=”Paste live channel ingest url here from Azure Media Services”
while :
do
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -r 30 -s 640×480 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -acodec libfaac -ab 48k -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 500k -r 30 -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -sc_threshold 0 -f flv $INGESTURI
sleep 10
done
```

You can check article how to stream from R[aspberry PI to Azure Media Services for additional details](http://gtrifonov.com/2015/07/02/streaming-live-video-from-raspberrypi-to-azure-media-services).

Same arguments should work for PC as well.You just need to check what device you passing in -i argument.

Comment: We are trying to post data in xamarin on RTMP url.

Comment: Then you need find component or write your own. I just googled and found https://components.xamarin.com/view/VitamioBinding. Probably there are more. I didn't try any of them to have opinion

Comment: Thanks George for your response but vitamio doesn't have good documentation for using the service.
I want to use c# code to solve this. But no luck after many days of research.